# Почему не работает скрипт для генерации PDF файла на стороне клиента?

Tags: javascript

Uncaught ReferenceError: jsPDF is not defined - ошибка при попытке инициализации newPdf

Я использую библиотеку jsPDF, разумеется подключил файл со скриптом после библиотеки и оба подключения сделал в body.

Вот скрипт:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    let specialHandler = {
        "#editor": function(element, renderer){
            return true;
        }
    }

    $('.mCS_img_loaded').click(function(){
        let newPdf = new jsPDF();

        newPdf.fromHTML($('#step_three .content').html(),15,15,{
            "width": 170,
            "elementHandlers": specialHandler
        })

        newPdf.save('hogo.pdf');
    });
});
```

Когда оставляю код без обертки $(document).ready(function(){});, событие клика вообще не обрабатывается.

Comment: Добавьте минимальный воспроизводимый код. В приведенном фрагменте jsPDF не подключается

Comment: Добавляю в body два тега:
<script src = "https://unpkg.com/jspdf@latest/dist/jspdf.umd.min.js"></ script>
<script src = "./js/pdf_generator.js"></ script>

Comment: без https:// в начале?

Comment: С ним. Вот гитхаб страничка библиотеки: https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При подключении из html библиотека определена в `jspdf`

`let newPdf = new jspdf.jsPDF();`

Comment: Теперь новая проблема, дальше в коде: Uncaught TypeError: newPdf.fromHTML is not a function.

Comment: не вижу в доках такого метода http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/